# Is it possible to use Generative Adversarial Networks (GANs) for text classification?

Tags: classification, gan

I am working on the classification of fake and real news. I did use a CNN Model for this problem and got satisfactory results. But, I was just wondering if it's at all possible to use any type of GAN for this sort of a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely. Grover ([axiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.12616)) is one such model, for example, made it to a bunch of news stories couple of months back.